# There is a simple Js script to change whole website font?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, font-family

I can’t find a simple JavaScript script ton change the font family of my website. I use a cookie plugin in wordpress and I search a script for when users don’t accept cookies.
Thanks for your help !

I’m a beginner in JavaScript but I know the element.style.fontFamily but not to set it.

Comment: Javascript is the wrong tool for changing fonts - use CSS. If you want to change the font conditionally, then put a class on a parent element using JS, eg. the `body`, and then base your font off that class. If you need more specific help on how to implement this, please add some demo code to the question which gives more context about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You should probably search for a wordpress tutorial how to add a child theme that's loading only local fonts. I guess you need GDPR-compliance (omitting external google fonts). See this post on [word exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/410789/remove-google-fonts-from-parent-theme-within-a-child-theme)

Answer (score 0):

```
const element = document.querySelector('#your-element');
const yourFont = 'sans-serif';
element.style.fontFamily = yourFont;
```

Change `element` and `yourFont` as you need.